# Does the Monotone Convergence Theorem apply?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have a doubt about this exercise, that asks if the MCT apply. I think it does, 'cause the hypothesis holds. But I'm not completly sure about it. Can you give me a hint about how to prove it?

[Exercise 4.H Bartle's book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjiG0.png)

Comment: Certainly it should be applicable.

Comment: It applies and we actually have $\int f_n d\lambda \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that what you need is:

- $f \ge f_n \ge 0$, for all $n \in \Bbb N$.
- $(f_n)_n \uparrow$.
- $f_n \to f$ in the pointwise sense.

So MCT is applicable in this situation.